# Matching objects in list based on id being same

Tags: java

I have **listOne** and **listTwo** with a bunch of objects. I want to remove items from **listOne** that are already there in **listTwo**, but the matching has to be only based on the **id**, the entire object need not be the same. If the id matches, the said object has to be removed from listOne. How do we achieve this with Java streams, please.

Comment: `listOne.removeIf(o1 -> listTwo.stream().anyMatch(o2 -> o2.id == o1.id));`

Comment: Or if list2 is long, `Set<IdType> idSet2 = list2.stream().map(i -> i.id).collect(toSet()); list1.removeIf(i -> idSet2.contains(i));`.

Answer (score 0):

What are the approximate sizes of the lists?  It might make sense to preprocess by scanning listTwo and making a Set of ids e.g. use `listOne.removeIf(thing -> idsFromListTwo.contains(thing.id))`.  The lookups in the Set will be faster than a sequential scan of a list.

```
package example.stackoverflow;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ListFilter {
    static record Thing(String id, Object data){};
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 100;
        int m = 10;
        List<Thing> listOne = makeListOfThings(n-m, n*2-m);
        List<Thing> listTwo = makeListOfThings(0, n);

        System.out.println("listOne: "+listOne);
        System.out.println("listTwo: "+listTwo);

        Collections.shuffle(listOne);
        Collections.shuffle(listTwo);

        System.out.println("After suffling...");
        System.out.println("listOne: "+listOne);
        System.out.println("listTwo: "+listTwo);

        List<Thing> copyOfOne = new ArrayList<>(listOne);
        
        long before = System.nanoTime();
        var idsTwo = listTwo.stream().map(Thing::id)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        listOne.removeIf(t -> idsTwo.contains(t.id));
        long after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("After removing things that were also in listTwo...");
        System.out.println("listOne (after): "+listOne);
        System.out.println("           Size: "+listOne.size());
        System.out.println("Time taken: "+((after-before)/1000.0)+" microseconds");
        
        System.out.println("Without using a Set...");
        before = System.nanoTime();
        copyOfOne.removeIf(t1 -> listTwo.stream().anyMatch(t2 -> t2.id.equals(t1.id)));
        after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("listOne (after): "+copyOfOne);
        System.out.println("           Size: "+copyOfOne.size());
        System.out.println("Time taken: "+((after-before)/1000.0)+" microseconds");
    }

    static List<Thing> makeListOfThings(int startingID, int endingID) {
        return IntStream.range(startingID, endingID)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Thing(String.valueOf(i), Objects.hash(i,System.nanoTime())))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
}
```